# how to use basic linux command to count the number of dot in every line then insert the value in each line in bash

Tags: linux, bash, txt

I process a text file with many domain like

```
abcd.efgh.ijkl.mnop
```

I hope to add a 3 at the same line no matter how it is at the beginning or at the end.

current I use

```
sed 's/[^.]//g' thetextfile | awk '{ print length }' > thenumber
```

then I use librecalc to combine them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Show example input, and show expected output...

Answer (score 2):

In plain `bash`, without using any external utility:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
    dots=${line//[^.]}
    printf '%d\t%s\n' ${#dots} "$line" 
done < file
```

Comment: `while read` is very inefficient, though; this is exactly the type of situation where you should use a tool like `sed` or Awk instead.

Comment: @tripleee Agreed. `awk` is blindingly fast compared to pure `bash` for this kind of tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Using a perl one-liner, taking advantage of [`tr`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#tr/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cdsr) returning the number of changes:

```sh
$ perl -ne 'print tr/././, " ", $_' input.txt
3 abcd.efgh.ijkl.mnop
6 abcd.efgh.ijkl.mnop...
4 abcd.efgh.ijkl.mnop.
```

Comment: Thank you. it works perfect in linux, but perl is not exist in DDWRT.

Answer (score 1):

The blindingly obvious answer is

```
awk -F . '{ print NF-1, $0 }' thetextfile >thenumber
```

Combining the results to a single file in an external utility seems like a humongous overcomplication; just process all the files in one go.

```
awk -F . '{ print NF-1, $0 }' * >allnumbers
```

or if your needs are more complex maybe something like

```
for file in *.txt; do
    echo "$0: processing $file ..." >&2
    awk -F . '{ print NF-1, $0 }' "$file"
done >allnumbers
```

The `-F .` says to use the literal dot as field separator, and `NF` is the number of fields (which will be one more than the number of separators; look up "fencepost error" if you don't understand why).

In more complex cases still, maybe append the output from each file with `>>allnumbers` inside the loop if you really need to (but understand that this is less efficient than only writing once after the `done`).

Awk's default output field separator is a single space; if you want to produce TSV (tab-separated output) or CSV, you can set `OFS="\t"` or `OFS=","` as required.

Comment: A corner case: `awk -F . '{ print NF-1, $0 }'` will print out `-1` on an empty line.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Good catch. You could obviously add a simple guard like `NF { print NF-1, $0 }` to prevent that.

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks for the feedback. I changed to a more specific wildcard to avoid the complications you point out.